# Can't control multiple divs with custom navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am using Slick Carousel where I have two `<div>`s that need to scroll when the next or previous buttons are clicked but only the second `<div>` is scrolling. Here is my HTML and Jquery:

JQuery:

```
    var test = $('.slider').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    variableWidth: true,
    prevArrow: $("#left-arrow"),
    nextArrow: $("#right-arrow")
});

$("#right-arrow").on('click', function () {
    test.slickNext();
});
$("#left-arrow").on('click', function () {
    test.slickPrev();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery-container" class="center">
    <div id="left-arrow"><img src="./resources/gallery-arrow.png" alt="Scroll Left" /></div>
    <div id="picture-container">
        <div class="upper-row carousel slider"></div>
        <div class="lower-row carousel slider"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right-arrow"><img src="./resources/gallery-arrow.png" alt="Scroll Left" /></div>
</div>
```

I am using JQuery 3.0.0. Only the "lower-row" is scrolling, the upper-row is not.

The images are loaded in dynamically through an Ajax call which is then calling my JQuery function.

If I try to use the #picture-container ID instead I can't click the arrows at all but I can drag the slides. However, when I drag the slides this way it won't stay where I drag it to and it resets back to the "0" position.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to call .slick() on your #gallery-container. Also let Slick add in the navigation buttons itself instead of hard coding them. I've stripped out a bunch of markup in my example and modified the javascript accordingly. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhigley/jmdu9au5/) of it working.

jQuery:

```
$('#gallery-container').slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  variableWidth: true,
  nextArrow: '<button><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>',
  prevArrow: '<button><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>'
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery-container" class="center">
  <div class="upper-row carousel slider">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/500/500?image=300" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="lower-row carousel slider">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/500/500?image=400" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```